# boost.asio. The possibility to expect the completion of any object in queue is necessary

Tags: boost, boost-asio

In asio:: io_service I insert objects. asio:: io_service::run() runs in several threads.
The possibility to expect the completion of any object in queue is necessary.
For example:

```
template <typename T>
struct handler {
   void operator()() {
      ....
   }
   T get() const {...}
};

asio::io_service ios;
ios.post(handler());
```

1. How I can refer to the object in queue?
2. How can I pause the main program loop, untill handler::operator() is executed?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are asking. Can you post compilable code instead of pseudo code? Is 'the object in queue' an instance of `struct handler`?

Comment: It is required, by the calling of handlet::get() to suspend the calling loop until handlet is executed.

Comment: @niXman - It sounds like you want one handler to execute at a time.  Is this correct?

Comment: No.
I need the handlers to be executed as usual until I call the method get() of any of them. But when I call get(), the calling thread should stop until the operator() of this object is executed.

Comment: Could you give us a bigger picture? What behavior are you trying to achieve? Rather than a vague `handler` object, describe what its purpose is.

Comment: In the operator() of the handler some calculations are executed. The result of calculation I get using the method get(). I need, at the calling of the method get(), the calling loop to be frozen until the operator() of this object is executed. But if I do not call get(), then this handler is executed as usual. There's no waiting of its processing then. code: http://liveworkspace.org/code/c601a9bf6226fe7e85fc9ba07c8dc933

Comment: it sounds like your various `handler` objects have dependencies with one another?  Otherwise, why would you need to stop the `io_service` reactor queue?

Comment: The liveworkspace code is helpful but I'm not entirely clear on the scenario.  Do you know which handler you will be calling get() on prior to posting the handler to io_service?  Also, when you call get() on one handler do all handlers that are running need to finish or just the one that get() is being called on?  Is there some data dependency between all of the handlers that are running concurrently? Thx

Comment: It is not known for any handlers will need to call get().
Handlers do not depend on each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I know so far:
1. Several handlers are executing on several threads.
2. Handlers run independently of each other.  There is no synchronization needed between threads for data/race conditions.
3. Get can be called on anyone handler. When called the handler should stop calculating and let another thread call handler::get().

This really seems more like a multi-threading / concurrency question then a boost::asio question.  At the moment I do not see a need to use an io_service.  It seems like several threads could just be started without an io_service and some synchronization could be used between the threads.

The thread calling Handler::get() needs to wait until the io_service thread running operator() completes its calculation before it can return.

Consider using a condition variable.  The handler::get() method can wait until the condition is met (i.e. operator() finishes its calculation).  The io_service thread that runs operator() would notify the main thread through the condition variable.

An example of one thread notifying another thread via a condition variable is [here](http://www.paulbridger.com/condition_variables).

Comment: I know that this can be implemented using a condition variable,
but suggested that this possibility should provide asio::io_service and its members/type_members.

Thank you.